# MPI send recv input arguments

Tags: c++, mpi

I have some problems with this part of code (I semplified it to be more clear).

```
//p is the number of processor (we suppose 2)
//vett is the vector who contains the elements to send
//disp is a vector whose elements are the index of the first element to send
//elem is a vector whose elements are the number of elements to send
//local_v is the destination vector (of dimension elem[rank])
//local_n is the number of elements that have to arrive (=elem[rank])
```

in my case the cycle is executed only one time

```
for(unsigned int i = 1; i < p; i++){
    if(rank==0){
        MPI_Send(&vett[disp[i]], elem[i], MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }else{
        MPI_Recv(&local_v, local_n, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
}
```

Processor1 sends to the other(in this case only processor2). I am not sure if I use correctly MPI_Send, in particular I'm not sure that the first input argument is correct...

Comment: I found the answer to my own question... in `MPI_Recv` is missing `[0]` after receive buffer, this is the entire line: `MPI_Recv(&local_v[0], local_n, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);`

Comment: If this is indeed the answer to your question, you should post it as an answer and then mark it as correct (I think there's a waiting period for the last part).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In `MPI_Recv` is missing `[0]` after receive buffer, this is the entire line:

```
MPI_Recv(&local_v[0], local_n, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```